# Broker not available when publishing to Redpanda broker

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama, redpanda

I get error `The broker is not available.` when I attempt to publish a message to a Redpanda broker. I am using the Sarama Go Kafka client. Here's how I create the producer and publish a message:

```
kafkaConfig := sarama.NewConfig()
kafkaConfig.Producer.Return.Successes = true
producer, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer(brokerList, kafkaConfig)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("NewSyncProducer failed: %s", err)
    return nil, err
}

message := sarama.ProducerMessage{Topic: "my-topic", Value: sarama.ByteEncoder([]byte("foo"))}

partition, offset, err := producer.SendMessage(&message)

if err != nil {
    log.Errorln(err)
}
```

`err` contains `kafka server: Broker not available. Not a client facing error, we should never receive this!!!`

In the systemctl log I see this when I publish a message:

```
WARN  2022-11-21 17:53:23,148 [shard 3] kafka - [127.0.0.1:46790] rejecting produce request: no disk space; bytes free less than configurable threshold
ERROR 2022-11-21 17:53:25,941 [shard 0] cluster - (rate limiting dropped 359 similar messages) storage space alert: free space at 18.208% on /var/lib/redpanda/data: 23.517GiB total, 4.282GiB free, min. free 0.000bytes. Please adjust retention policies as needed to allow writing again
```

What setting controls this threshold?

Answer (score 1):

@user2233706 - you need to create the topic first. Otherwise ensure that etc/redpanda/redpanda.yaml has autocreate topics set to true.

Comment: Yes, the topic already exists.